# How to display images from image path save in DB

Tags: php, image, foreach, yii2

I'm trying to display images in foreach loop but its not working. I dont know what is wrong with my code. I hope someone could help me. Below is my code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ($query as $query): ?>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src='".$query['path']."' alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right">RM <?= $query['product_price'] ?></h4>
                            <h4><a href="#"><?= $query['product_name'] ?></a>
                            </h4>
                            <p><?= $query['product_desc'] ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>                    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<img src='".$query['path']."' alt="">
```

To

```
<img src='<?= $query['path'] ?>' alt="">
```